# Can someone clarify this code snippet that reverses a string?

Tags: java, string, loops

Can someone explain how this code works, in particular the `for` loop part as I get the rest of it.

```
String x = "hello world";

for(int i = x.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    System.out.print(x.charAt(i));
}
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Comment: What exactly is hard for you to understand? This code loops *backwards* (from the end of the string to its beginning).

Comment: Honestly, after looking back at it now I don't see why I didn't get it myself. The explanations were all great and thanks for answering my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of your string as an array of characters. In this array obviously each character will have an index.

```
h e l l o   w o r l d
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

The array index is zero based. Because your loop begins at the length of the string -1. Your loop will start at 11-1 which is 10. Then it simply prints out one character at a time working backwords.

The first iteration the index or i value is 10, so charAt(10) will print out the 'd'

The second iteration the index is one less than 10 because you are decrementing in the for loop. So 10-1 = 9. charAt(9) will print out 'l'

This will continue until your loop reaches the end condition where the index i is equal to 0. The loop then stops and the program is finished.

Essentially all you are doing is printing out the string backwords. So your end result will be 
   **dlrow olleh**

Answer (score 1):

It's a basic for loop that starts with the first position being the end of the string, and then decreases by 1 at every iteration (and stops when the `i` is `< 0`). It could also be written as

```
String x = "hello world";
for (int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++) {
  System.out.print(x.charAt(x.length() - (i+1)));
}
```

Which will also print

```
dlrow olleh
```

Answer (score 1):

The `for` loop:

`int i=x.length()-1` create an integer called `i` which is equal to the number of the final character in the string.

`i>=0` keep running this loop (everything inside the braces) while the value `i` is greater than or equal to 0. 0 is the number of the first character in the string. i.e. in the string "Hello", the numbers of the characters are `[0]H, [1]e, [2]l, [3]l, [4]o`.

`i--` on each iteration of this loop, decrease the value ("decrement") the value of `i`.

---

The line of code within the `for` loop:

`System.out.print(x.charAt(i));` print the character at the location given by the value 'i' i.e. "the character in the string `x` at the location `i`.

---

The resulting behaviour is:

1. print out character 10 from string x -> `d`
2. print out character 9 from string x  -> `l`
3. print out character 8 from string x  -> `r`
4. print out character 7 from string x  -> `o`
5. print out character 6 from string x  -> `w`
6. print out character 5 from string x  ->
7. print out character 4 from string x  -> `o`
8. print out character 3 from string x  -> `l`
9. print out character 2 from string x  -> `l`
10. print out character 1 from string x  -> `e`
11. print out character 0 from string x  -> `h`

Please then read this:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it is easier to understand well formatted code.

```
String x = "hello world";

for (int i = x.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    System.out.print(x.charAt(i));
}
```

Now we can break it down.

```
int i = x.length() - 1
```

Initial an `int` variable, `i`, with the value `x.length() - 1`, which is the last index of the string (the index of a string/array is 0 to length - 1).

```
i >= 0;
```

While the current index `i` is greater than or equal to the first index (`0`), print the character to the console; `System.out.print(x.charAt(i));`.

```
i--
```

Decrement the index `i` so it refers to the previous character.

Answer (score 0):

A for loop works like this:

For ( Initialization; Statement; Incrementation) { INSERT CODE HERE }

Initialization:
In your code, the for loop creates a variable i that is set equal to the number of characters in "hello world" - 1. Since there are 11 characters in the String, 11-1 = 10. Therefore i = 10.

Statement:
In a for loop, there is a statement. If the statement is true, the code inside the body will execute. Since i (which is 11) is greater than or equal to 0, the code will execute (after incrementation).

Incrementation:
The variable i now goes down by 1. It is now equal to 10. The code will execute now.

Code:
X.charAt(i) gives the character that is at the index of the string X. Since i is equal to 10, the program will give you the letter at the 10th index, which is "d".

Statement:
The program now goes to the statement again. i=10. 10 is greater than or equal to 0. i is now equal to 9. The code will now execute, giving the letter at the 9th index, "l".

This will keep going until i reaches -1. Once it reaches -1, it is no longer greater than or equal to 0, so the program will stop, giving you "dlrow olleh"